# Waiting for the script to add elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple js code that loads xml and adds an image to the page. At the botton of the code is a function that pops up an alert when you click an image. I have an image that is added in the html, so there are two images. My problem is that the alert fires for the image that is added in the html but not for the image that is added by the js / xml. I think the problem is that the click function is hit before the second image is loaded into the html?? Is this the problem? If not what is and can you please tell me how I solve this. Thanks.

You can see the two images here: http://demo.digitaldraping.com/configurator/test/

HTML

```
<div class="Fabric"><img src="img/swatch/2016.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="Canvas"></div>  

</div><!-- #Config -->

<script src="js.js"></script>
```

JS

```
// Load XML
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.xml', // name of file you want to parse
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parse,
        error: function(){alert("Error: Something wrong with XML");}
    });

function parse(document){
    $(document).find("Swatch").each(function(){
        $(".Fabric").append(
        '<img class="' + $(this).attr('name') + '" alt="' +     $(this).attr('alt') + '"  title="' + $(this).attr('title') + '" src="img/swatch/' + $(this).attr('name') + '.jpg">'
        );
    }); 
} //function parse End



$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".Fabric img").click(function () {
            alert("image clicked");
    });

}); //document.ready End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `on()` will allow you to listen to events via bubbling.

It would be better to listen it at a closer level than document

Change

```
$(".Fabric img").click(function () {
        alert("image clicked");
});
```

to

```
$(".Fabric").on("click", "img", function () {
        alert("image clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding events on dynamically added elements.

Bind the event on `document` or container that is already on the page when it loads.

Sample:

```
$(document).on('click', '.Fabric img', function(){
        alert("image clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with dynamic element use event delgation model to register event handlers using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', ".Fabric img", function () {
        alert("image clicked");
});
```

If `.Fabric` is a static element which is present at dom load then you can use

```
$('.Fabric').on('click', 'img', function () {
        alert("image clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function parse(document){
 $(document).find("Swatch").each(function(){
    $(".Fabric").append(
    '<img class="' + $(this).attr('name') + '" alt="' +     $(this).attr('alt') + '"  title="' + $(this).attr('title') + '" src="img/swatch/' + $(this).attr('name') + '.jpg">'
    );
 }); 
}
```

Change to :

```
function parse(document){
 $(document).find("Swatch").each(function(){
    var _image = '<img class="' + $(this).attr('name') + '" alt="' +     $(this).attr('alt') + '"  title="' + $(this).attr('title') + '" src="img/swatch/' + $(this).attr('name') + '.jpg">';
    $(".Fabric").append(_image);
    _image.click(function(){
            alert('Clicked me !');
          });

    );
 }); 
}
```